# Python brings empty dataframe with no reason

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using pd.read_sql to generate dataframes. I'm using parameters in a list to generate separate dataframes based on filters. I did same query from my script in python on database and it worked.
In SQL database I always had data returned for months 1,2,3 and/or project x,y. But python SOMETIMES doesn't bring nonthing and I don't know. This generate empty dataframe
if I put months like [1,'2',3] sometimes the where condition works, but in my database the field is varchar, I don't why if I put int in a list the data comes or depend on type the filter doesn't works

```
server = 'xxxxx'
database = 'mydatabase'
username = 'user'
password = '*************'
driver = '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'
turbodbc_options = 'options'
timeout = '1'


project = ['x','y']
months = ['1','2','3']
def generatefile():
    for pr in project:  
        for index in months:
            print(type(index))
            print(index) 
            print(pr)
            db = pd.read_sql('''select * from table WHERE monthnumber =(?)and pro=(?)''',conn,params={str(index),(pr)})
            print(db)
            print("generate...")          
            db.to_excel('C:\\localfile\\' + pr + '\\' + pr + tp + str(index) + 'file.xlsx',index=False,engine='xlsxwriter' ),index=False,engine='xlsxwriter' )
            
generatefile()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the difference between:

1.

```
sql = '''
select * from table WHERE monthnumber = '1' and pro= 'x'
'''
```

2. 

```
sql = '''
select * from table WHERE monthnumber = 1 and pro= 'x'
'''
```

so, the sql should be something like below, if the field is varchar.

```
db = pd.read_sql(f'''
select * from table WHERE monthnumber ='{index}'and pro='{pr}'
''',conn)
```